# Enigmail: Adding the User ID failed

Tags: thunderbird, enigmail

I wanted to add a User ID to my private GPG key such that I can use it for two email addresses. I went to Enigmail -> Key Management, selected my key and chose Manage User IDs. After entering the new email address (along with a name), I got the following error:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of re-installations of Thunderbird, Enigmail and GnuPG(2) I figured out the very simple problem: There was a `secring.gpg.lock` file along with `secring.gpg` which obviously prohibited any changes. Must have been an artefact from a former dual-boot use.